Circuit protection 5V for sensor
I have a circuit that uses a C11708MA. Being expensive, I'd like not to burn it. What kind of protection should I include, against what factors?
The datasheet says the supply voltage should be between 4.75 and 5.25 V. The power supply goes from a power bank to a Raspberry pi, from there to a microcontroller Xiao ESP32S3 which sits on the same PCB as the sensor. The board and sensor live in a plastic case.
On the power lines, the circuit is very simple, with a direct connection between the 5V and ground outputs of the MCU and the corresponding inputs of the sensor. The rest of the components are more robust.

Can I assume there won't be an over voltage from the Pi? (The microcontroller doesn't seem to have any regulation for the 5V channel).
Is the case enough to prevent ESD from handling it? There will be an exposed USB socket when the instrument is not powered.
Anything else I haven't considered? The Pi is definitely doing current limiting, so I don't think I need a fuse.


Seems worthwhile to pay attention to the footnote in the datasheet for the impedance of the video output and the type of opamp buffer they recommend for it.

Yes, I am leaving out the circuitry in between. Those are much more robust.

If there's any possibility of an overvoltage, the brute-force protection is a crowbar circuit. The TL431 datasheet from Texas Instruments shows how to achieve this, with a very precisely defined "trip" voltage, on page 28:

I've also included the shunt regulator schematic, which could be less harsh on the supply, but will require careful choice of that upper-left resistance. Both designs impose a very precisely controlled cap on voltage \$V_O\$. You would choose resistances R1 and R2 according to this:
$$ V_O\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}=2.5V $$
If, for instance, you require voltage to be clamped at +5.2V, then set \$V_O=5.2V\$, and solve for R1 and R2, aiming for values between 1kΩ and 10kΩ.
The crowbar design will literally short-circuit the supply, blowing the fuse when \$V_O\$ exceeds the limit set by R1 and R2.
The biggest problem you face when trying to eliminate fast transients is parasitic capacitance, which will couple transient events from a regulator's input directly to its output, to which the regulator is unable to react quickly enough. One way to mitigate this is to ensure that capacitance at the regulator output is significant by comparison, but you can't just attach extra capacitance without affecting regulator stability, and you could end up with ringing which is just as problematic as the transients you are trying to suppress.
That can be addressed using series resistance, but since that would incur a voltage drop, it would require a voltage source greater than 5V to begin with. However, if you did have access to such a source, perhaps from a boost converter, then you have more options available:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I used the 7805 here to derive 5V from a 10V source, but the main player is R1, which together with C1 and C2 form a low ESR, low-pass filter, able to remove most of the switching noise and any other transients from the source. With a load of 100mA attached to B, R1 will develop a little over \$100mA \times 10\Omega = 1V\$, leaving a further 4V of overhead for the linear regulator to dispense with. This post regulation will have no trouble dealing with anything messy remaining after R1/C have done their work.
There will be some power wasted in the 7805, of course:
$$ P=(9V-5V) \times 100mA = 400mW $$
If your DC-DC converter or the linear regulator has a built-in current limit, then you can safely attach the crowbar from before, even without a fuse (though the fuse is still advised, perhaps a fusible 10Ω resistor for R1), so not only do you have transient suppression, but also protection against failure of either regulator. To this end, consider the 78L05, with built in ≈100mA current limit and thermal shutdown.

A practical problem with the crowbar is that it will protect the circuit, but it will reset the MCU, which is not very practical .

@Davidmh If you've had a regulation failure, I would think that a reset MCU is the least of your worries, but you know better than me what's important in your application.

It depends on the failure mode. If it is a transient spike. Of course, for a proper failure overvolting the 5V lane, not booting is the right thing.

@Davidmh fair point, the problem I saw was that you have a 5V supply, and any attempt to sense current, or limit it in any way would incur a voltage drop. The crowbar violently side-steps this, and your complaint is valid. The device consumes $\frac{60mW}{5V}=12mA$ max., and for the shunt clamp design a source resistance of 10Ω would drop $12mA\times 10=0.12V$. If that's acceptable, then the clamp using a transistor (perhaps darlington pair) instead of triac might work. If you had more than 5V available, a lot of headaches go away.

I could boost from the USB and get more volts, but then again, we have one more component to fail. Is that along what you are thinking?

@Davidmh My thinking is that to prevent very fast and short transients, the best approach is probably an RC filter, or capacitance multiplier, and/or current limiter, and a linear regulator that you know you can trust. Maybe also a crowbar that can't affect anything prior if current is limited. There are more options when you have, say 6V or 7V to play with. It sounds a lot to do to protect a single element, I admit, but I think this is the cost of "guarantees".

I believe you will need voltage translators to go between the 3.3V ESP32 and the 5V Hamamatsu device. Vih minimum is Vdd - 0.25V so it needs the full swing.
They will provide some protection for the data lines. You can also add a bit of series resistance and low-capacitance transient absorbers (as for USB lines).
For the power supply you could add a 5V very-low-dropout LDO with at least a 20V maximum input voltage to protect against rogue PD modes of the power bank, or better yet use a proper regulated power supply that has OVP and current limiting.

I actually skipped the shifter because it actually works, but if it provides extra protection I'll put it back in.
The best match I can find for the LDO is HT7550-1. My concern is that the USB itself has a voltage range output, and adding the 0.1 V dropout may put it outside of spec. Is that a reasonable concern? (I can measure it but that would only give me the answer at that point in time).
On the power supply, I need it to be portable and hand held, I think what you mean is wall-plugged, right?

Maybe. The USB spec, unfortunately, is much wider than the Hamamatsu device requires to work within specifications, so you are on thin ice. You could buy or build a DC-DC converter - isolated or buck-boost (or boost followed by an LDO). This is kind of a conflicting requirement to your question, which is about protection. Anything that can turn 4V into 4.75~5.25V can probably turn it into 6 or 7V if it fails.
